# public void OnBackPressed() vs public override void OnBackPressed() vs protected override void OnBackPressed()

Tags: java, xamarin

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTWcP.jpg)

I just want to see whats differences between these three types?

In all my situations i'm using

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
```

My first question is what the difference between above?

And second is it my back press kills my current activity and goes to previous?
What if i want to go in before two activitys?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java OOP Public vs Private vs Protected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461496/java-oop-public-vs-private-vs-protected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. all of them are the same. 
   doesn't matter if they are public or protected, as long as they aren't private.
   and don't have to write that you Overrides the method. it can help you when writing a code to see if you overridden the method, as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)
2. The default implementation simply finishes the current activity. if you don't use the super method, you can do what ever you want.

you can read more about that [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).